# Copying dates to a column from another table with criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to do the following:

One table in the database is called `service_state_history`, that table has three columns:

- `service_id` - which refers to the id of the service that the service_state is related to. (it's nor foreign key because the relation is done in the JPA code in this case).
- `state_started` column which has `DATETIME` values, that indicate whenever the state on that row has started.
- `state` column which describes the state of that history entry and has following VARCHAR-values: (`STANDBY`, `IN PROGRESS`, `DONE`)

The other table in the database is called `services`, that table has two relevant columns:

- `id` BIGINT
- `done_date` DATETIME

Now, what I'm supposed to do is update the `done_date` column in `services` from the `service_state_history` table's column `state_started`, when the `state` column's value in the row is `DONE` and the `service_id` value in matches `id` in `services`.

How does that translate into SQL?

Comment: Can be done with either a JOIN or a sub-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get all the records that will be updating the destination table, you will use the results generated from:

```
SELECT service_id, state_started, state
FROM service_state_history
WHERE state = 'DONE'
```

To perform the `UPDATE` you will need to `JOIN` this result set to the destination table on the identity column and use the `state_started` in the update. Something like:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.done_date = ssh.state_started
FROM services s
INNER JOIN service_state_history ssh ON ssh.service_id = s.id
WHERE ssh.state = 'DONE'
```

Comment: Perfectly straightforward - but it may be worthwhile to avoid "over updating".  For example, ssh may have very many records for s (I'm assuming services might be run multiple times), so you might want to only update s to the "latest" value of a matching ssh (adding a group by and a max), and avoid updating s where the row is is already current.  This may be especially important where there are triggers on s.

Comment: @Clay I can see your point and agree in principle, but the OP hasn't specified any of that information. Without a more detailed question, all of that is going to be based on assumptions.

Comment: agreed 100% - I'm still smarting from some recent experience with the problem and figured it wouldn't hurt to throw a btw into the OP's thinking (or anybody else that may read this later).